# Javascript: Change css child nodes in id

Tags: javascript, css

Perhaps the answer is relatively simple, but I just started with Javascript and I can't seem to achieve my goal:

I've got this piece of CSS code:

```
#tabmenu li a {
background: #ACBACF;
}
```

Now I want to change the background, but not only for #tabmenu, li or a, but all of them.
How do I do this with Javascript?

Edit:
This is a button with a background, I want to know how to change the values of the css part. So it's not only background, but also padding and stuff, but to make it simple, let's say I just want to change the background with javascript.

HTML:

```
<ul id="tabmenu">
       <li>
           <a href="#index">Home</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Edit 2:
I can't change the HTML or the CSS, because I want to create a userscript (Greasemonkey).

Comment: Can you define all of them?

Comment: Please, post some HTML code as well and be more specific on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Well to set css for all three at once, use commas to sperate them
   `#tabmenu, #tabmenu li, #tabmenu li a { background: #ACBACF;}`

Comment: I edited the question. @gbtimmon, thank you for your reply, but that's not really what I mean. I can't touch the HTML or the CSS, because I'm changing it with a userscript.

Comment: try this document.getElementById('tabmenu').style.backgroundColor='#123456';

Comment: Use JQuery, or the like, especially until you understand java script better. There is a million different way to solve what you are asking all with their own sets of pros and cons and I am having trouble figuring out where to start based off your question alone.

Comment: Here's a fiddle perhaps you can explain what the expected result is because this is changing "all of them".  http://jsfiddle.net/jstx/MPzu9/

Comment: Thanks. I made a fiddle too to show you what I mean. It's a little difficult to explain, so I hope you'll understand: http://jsfiddle.net/MPzu9/4/

Comment: Not the best approach but try this. Open http://jsfiddle.net/3eVv3/show/ open console and run this: document.getElementById('tabmenu').style.cssText = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0], "").cssText;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think setting css directly from Javascript is the best approach. It leads to a lot of inline code and doesn't play very well with the style you defined in an external file. If your going for heavy modification of css, I suggest injecting a custom style tag inside the dom:

```
var style = document.createElement("style")
style.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
style.innerHTML = "#tabmenu li a {\
    background: red;\
}";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style)
```

The "\" at the end of lines are needed in Javascript when using multiline string values.

In the end, if you follow this route, i would suggest writing the css code in a text editor, then pack it with something like https://csscompressor.net/ (this will give you a single-line string) and copy-paste the result between the brackets.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick. It's not really "heavy modification", just changing an existing css rule. Anyways, I can continue my script. Thanks again!